# change rails association from has_many to has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to change my model association from a has_many (which works) to a has_one but I'm running into issues.

when i go to:

```
localhost:3000/users/1/security_badge/new
```

i get this in the logs

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass):
```

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :security_badge, dependent: :destroy
end
```

SecurityBadge model:

```
class SecurityBadge < ApplicationRecord    
  belongs_to :user    
end
```

my routes:

```
  resources :users do
    resource :security_badge
  end
```

some of my controller security_badges_controller:

```
  before_action :set_user, only: [:index, :show, :new, :edit, :create, :update]
  before_action :set_security_badge, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @security_badge = @user.security_badge.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @security_badge = @user.security_badge.new(security_badge_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @security_badge.save
        format.html { redirect_to user_security_badge_path(@security_badge.user), notice: 'Security badge was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end

    def set_security_badge
      @security_badge = SecurityBadge.find(params[:id])
    end
```

**Update**

this is in my _form:

```
<%= form_with(model: [@user, security_badge], local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if security_badge.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(security_badge.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this security_badge from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% security_badge.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, autofocus:true, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <br>
  <div class="row float-right">
    <div class="col-md-12 actions">
        <%= link_to "Cancel", user_path(@security_badge.user), id: 'cancel', class: 'btn btn-outline-secondary' %>
        <%= form.submit "Submit", id: "submit", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    </div>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

new view template:

```
<%= render 'form', security_badge: @security_badge %>
```

Comment: Do you have `before_action :set_user`?

Comment: check if you have callback method `before_action :set_user` on your `SecurityBadgesController`

Comment: yes i have the before actions, just updated the question with it.  thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@user.build_security_badge` (method provided by the `has_one` association macro) instead of `@user.security_badge.new` (`security_badge` is nil, that's why you get an error).

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference

Comment: thanks but I'm getting a weird error when I use `@user.build_security_badge` saying `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method user_security_badges_path for ....` which is kind of good because now it means that security_badge is no longer nil, but I can't find that pluralized path anywhere.  notice it says `security_badges` with an `s` instead of `user_security_badge_path`

Comment: updated the question with my form and new templates.  not sure how that path is getting generated though.

Comment: the template error was due to having a nested form and using a singular resource route, for anyone who may have the same issue in the future here's more details on how to get a singular route with a nested form  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53473476/one-to-one-association-with-nested-route